# Name mixup in hall of fame/photo of the week

Tags: bug, status-completed, featured-photo, hall-of-fame

The author names in the Hall of Fame for the 2 most recent photos are switched! I took the photo of St. Peter's Basilica for the April 18th Famous Buildings competition and Aganju took "squeezing through spooky canyon" from the April 25th Claustrophobic competition. The mixup also carries over to the current photo of the week section on the sidebar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh crap. Thanks for letting me know. I got caught out again making copy/paste errors after I copied your HoF section, and mixed up which section I was pasting new data into.

Sorry for the mixup. I think I've fixed it now. =)

Comment: Looks good! Thank you!